# How to generate a Barcode using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, barcode

I am developing an IOS app using Swift and Firebase. I want to generate a Barcode for each user and provide discounts to them. How can I generate a Barcode? Which Barcode scanning device is suitable?

I have googled and read, but they are not useful. Please shed some light and provide any useful link or website.

I have tried below code, but it's not generating an Barcode. I don't see any output/Barcode image. My screen was empty.

```
@IBAction func gen(_ sender: UIButton) {
    imageDisplay.image = generateBarcodeFromString(from: tfInput.text!)

}




/*     imageDisplay.image = generateBarcodeFromString(from: tfInput.text!)
```

*/

```
func generateBarcodeFromString(from string: String)-> UIImage?{

let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii)

let filter = CIFilter(name: "CICode128BarcodeGenerator")

 filter?.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")

    let transform = __CGAffineTransformMake(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10) /*          CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 3, y: 3)
```

*/

```
    if let output = filter?.outputImage?.applying(transform){

        return UIImage(ciImage: output)

    }

    return nil

}
```

Comment: what you tried till now?

Comment: I tried that duplicate post, but its not working or not useful. as it is 2 years old.

Comment: Then you should either edit your question or ask a new question, showing what you tried and the specific problems you are experiencing.

Comment: it's better I will edit it.

Comment: @Paulw11 I have edited the question.

Comment: Neither of those blocks of code will add anything to the screen. They will return a `UIImage` that you could put in a `UIImageView`. Did they return a non-nil value?

Comment: @Paulw11 I have tried this code, but I got an error. When I am returning nil, error is "Nil is not compatible with return type 'UIImage' ".

Comment: "func generateBarcodeFromString(from string: String)-> UIImage{
    
    let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii)
     
    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CICode128BarcodeGenerator")
        
     filter?.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
        
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 3, y: 3)  /* __CGAffineTransformMake(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10)
*/
        
        
        if let output = filter?.outputImage?.applying(transform){
        
            
            return UIImage(ciImage: output)
        }
        return nil

    }"

Comment: Please suggest.

Comment: The error message is quite clear if you know the basics of Swift: either make the return type an optional, or don't return nil. My advice is to make the function return `UIImage?` instead of `UIImage`... and indeed this is what they do in the duplicate.

Comment: @EricAya I tried returning UIImage but when I return UIImage I am getting an error  "cannot convert return expression of type 'UIImage!.Type(aka 'ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<UIImage>.Type') to return type 'UIImage' "

Comment: @EricAya If I return nil, getting error  "Nil is incompatible with return type 'UIImage' "

Comment: Please suggest.

Comment: Read my comment again... You're missing an important part.

Comment: func generateBarcodeFromString(from string: String)-> UIImage?{
    
    let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii)
     
    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CICode128BarcodeGenerator")
        
     filter?.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
        
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 3, y: 3)  /* __CGAffineTransformMake(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10)
*/
        
        
        if let output = filter?.outputImage?.applying(transform){
        
            return UIImage(ciImage: output)
 
        }
        
        return nil
    
    }
}

Comment: Thank you, I just cleared the error.

Comment: Though I cleared the error, barcode is not generating, please suggest.

Comment: After doing enough research I did not find any good document, So I have posted here.